# I am trying to create a dynamic spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

What I want is to populate area spinner based on city selected from the first spinner. I have attached necessary code. If anyone need anything else please fell free to ask. I am sorry but I am new to this. Thank you in advance.

select_location_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#C51162"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="@string/selectCity"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/citySpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/selectArea"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/areaSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

string.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Navigation Drawer</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="drawer_open">Open Navigation Drawer</string>
    <string name="drawer_close">Close Navigation Drawer</string>
    <string name="selectCity">Select City</string>
    <string name="selectArea">Select Area</string>

    <string-array name="drawerItems">
        <item>Location</item>
        <item>Ready for Delivery</item>
        <item>Order Cake</item>
        <item>About us</item>
        <item>Setting</item>
        <item>Login</item>
        <item>My Orders</item>
        <item>My Cart</item>
        <item>Help</item>
        <item>Contact us</item>
        <item>Rate us</item>
        <item>Share</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="cities">
        <item>Ahmedabad</item>
        <item>Baroda</item>
        <item>Surat</item>
        <item>Mumbai</item>
        <item>Pune</item>
        <item>Banglore</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="ahmedabad_area">
        <item>Maninagar</item>
        <item>C.T.M</item>
        <item>C.G. Road</item>
        <item>Satellite</item>
        <item>S.G. Highway</item>
        <item>Navarangpura</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="baroda_area">
        <item>Alkapuri</item>
        <item>Fateganj</item>
        <item>Jaeahar Nagar</item>
        <item>Karali</item>
        <item>Mandavi</item>
        <item>Masar Road</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="surat_area">
        <item>Athwa</item>
        <item>Bajipura</item>
        <item>Cenral Colony</item>
        <item>Hajira</item>
        <item>Kamrej</item>
        <item>Lajpor</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="mumbai_area">
        <item>Adarsha Nagar</item>
        <item>Thane</item>
        <item>Centacruz</item>
        <item>Andheri</item>
        <item>Varsova</item>
        <item>Dadar</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="pune_area">
        <item>Akurdi</item>
        <item>Bavada</item>
        <item>Chakan</item>
        <item>Daund</item>
        <item>Earth Stn</item>
        <item>Ganeshkhind</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="banglore_area">
        <item>Indira Nagar</item>
        <item>Jay Nagar</item>
        <item>TipSandra</item>
        <item>Kora Mangala</item>
        <item>Rajaji Nagar</item>
        <item>White Field</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

LocationSelection.java

```
   package com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;

public class LocationSelection extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_location_layout);

        Spinner citySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.citySpinner);
        Spinner areaSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.areaSpinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.cities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        citySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.ahmedabad_area,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        areaSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);

        citySpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) {
                        adapter1.clear();

                        int stringArrayResource = 0;
                        switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            stringArrayResource = R.array.ahmedabad_area;
                            break;
                        }
                        adapter1.addAll(getResources().getStringArray(
                                stringArrayResource));
                        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });
    }

}
```

LogCat

```
    07-08 09:24:08.274: D/OpenGLRenderer(2879): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-08 09:24:08.278: D/(2879): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42d7740, tid 2879
07-08 09:24:08.754: D/Atlas(2879): Validating map...
07-08 09:24:09.145: D/libEGL(2879): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
07-08 09:24:09.146: D/libEGL(2879): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
07-08 09:24:09.156: D/libEGL(2879): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
07-08 09:24:09.166: D/(2879): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf039490, tid 2897
07-08 09:24:09.204: I/OpenGLRenderer(2879): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-08 09:24:09.266: D/OpenGLRenderer(2879): Enabling debug mode 0
07-08 09:24:09.368: W/EGL_emulation(2879): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-08 09:24:09.368: W/OpenGLRenderer(2879): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaf035800, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-08 09:24:09.468: I/Choreographer(2879): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-08 09:24:18.176: W/EGL_emulation(2879): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-08 09:24:18.177: W/OpenGLRenderer(2879): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb43c6c20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-08 09:24:18.211: D/AndroidRuntime(2879): Shutting down VM
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879): Process: com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer, PID: 2879
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:638)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:75)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:658)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:466)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear(ArrayAdapter.java:258)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer.LocationSelection$1.onItemSelected(LocationSelection.java:35)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:914)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:903)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:48)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:873)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-08 09:24:18.211: E/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

please help me to know how can I populate areas in spinner2 based on city selected in spinner1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is a working sample.  It took a bit longer than expected but it works.  The idea as that you get the text of the citySpinner and use that to get the resource id for the string array needed for the areaSpinner.  The code to handle the item selection is placed in the onStart event so that it only fires once.

#### MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private String TAG = "MainActivity";

  private Activity mActivity;
  private Spinner mCitySpinner;
  private Spinner mAreaSpinner;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    mActivity = this;

    mCitySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.citySpinner);
    mAreaSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.areaSpinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.cities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    mCitySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

    mCitySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
          Log.d(TAG, "mCitySpinner.onItemSelected");

          String city = mCitySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
          Log.d(TAG, String.format("city:%s", city));

          String name = String.format("%s_area", city).toLowerCase();
          Log.d(TAG, String.format("name:%s", name));

          String packageName = getPackageName();
          Log.d(TAG, String.format("packageName:%s", packageName));

          Resources res = getResources();
          int rid = res.getIdentifier(name, "array", packageName);
          Log.d(TAG, String.format("rid:%d", rid));

          String[] items = res.getStringArray(rid);
          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
          mAreaSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
          Log.d(TAG, "mCitySpinner.onNothingSelected");

          String[] items = new String[]{};
          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
          mAreaSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });

  }  
}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#C51162"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="@string/selectCity"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/citySpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/selectArea"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/areaSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### strings.xml

```
<string name="app_name">Navigation Drawer</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="drawer_open">Open Navigation Drawer</string>
<string name="drawer_close">Close Navigation Drawer</string>
<string name="selectCity">Select City</string>
<string name="selectArea">Select Area</string>

<string-array name="drawerItems">
    <item>Location</item>
    <item>Ready for Delivery</item>
    <item>Order Cake</item>
    <item>About us</item>
    <item>Setting</item>
    <item>Login</item>
    <item>My Orders</item>
    <item>My Cart</item>
    <item>Help</item>
    <item>Contact us</item>
    <item>Rate us</item>
    <item>Share</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="cities">
    <item>Ahmedabad</item>
    <item>Baroda</item>
    <item>Surat</item>
    <item>Mumbai</item>
    <item>Pune</item>
    <item>Banglore</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="ahmedabad_area">
    <item>Maninagar</item>
    <item>C.T.M</item>
    <item>C.G. Road</item>
    <item>Satellite</item>
    <item>S.G. Highway</item>
    <item>Navarangpura</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="baroda_area">
    <item>Alkapuri</item>
    <item>Fateganj</item>
    <item>Jaeahar Nagar</item>
    <item>Karali</item>
    <item>Mandavi</item>
    <item>Masar Road</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="surat_area">
    <item>Athwa</item>
    <item>Bajipura</item>
    <item>Cenral Colony</item>
    <item>Hajira</item>
    <item>Kamrej</item>
    <item>Lajpor</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="mumbai_area">
    <item>Adarsha Nagar</item>
    <item>Thane</item>
    <item>Centacruz</item>
    <item>Andheri</item>
    <item>Varsova</item>
    <item>Dadar</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="pune_area">
    <item>Akurdi</item>
    <item>Bavada</item>
    <item>Chakan</item>
    <item>Daund</item>
    <item>Earth Stn</item>
    <item>Ganeshkhind</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="banglore_area">
    <item>Indira Nagar</item>
    <item>Jay Nagar</item>
    <item>TipSandra</item>
    <item>Kora Mangala</item>
    <item>Rajaji Nagar</item>
    <item>White Field</item>
</string-array>
```

### Note: This code is for the animated hamburger menu

#### MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  private String TAG = "MainActivity";

  private Activity mActivity;
  private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
  private ListView mListView;
  private String[] mItems;
  private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    mActivity = this;

    mItems = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(mActivity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, mItems));
    mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(mActivity, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
      @Override
      public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("onDrawerClosed");
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        syncState();
      }

      @Override
      public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("onDrawerOpened");
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        syncState();
      }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
  }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/drawer_frame"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      />

  </RelativeLayout>

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

#### styles.xml

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  </style>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
  </style>
  <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
  super.onStart();
  citySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        String city = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String name = String.format("%s_area", city);
        Resources res = getResources();
        int id = res.getIdentifier(name, "array", getPackageName());
        String[] items = res.getStringArray(id);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        areaSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
      }

      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        String[] items = new String[]{};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        areaSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: sorry I am new to this so do not understand your code. Can you have a look at the below answer and let me know why does it crash? I did exactly the same given in the answer below.

Comment: I am posting a logcat and LocationSelection.java please have a look at it and tell me what is my mistake. thank you in advance :)

Comment: Sure. I will create a working sample for you this morning.

Comment: Please see my latest post for the complete solution as a working sample.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you so so so much.... its worked.... you made my day... was struggling from pas few days for this. Finally... Thanx a lot friend. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @akkie4396, it's my pleasure.  Let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: can you give me a link on tutorial for how to animate drawerToggle icon while it open and closed. I want to do it in Eclipse not for Android Studio. Thankx :)

Answer (score 1):

@akkie4396, this will do it.

#### styles.xml

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  </style>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
  </style>
  <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: thank for your reply but this gives me an error in styles,xml saying ' Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
 'android:Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Comment: Ok I fixed the above issue. Now the error I get in is "Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions"   Please help.

Comment: I have posted my question. Please @itsben help me. Here is the link.                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343387/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v7-app-actionbardisplayoptions

Comment: Hey bro, above problem is also solved. But your style.xml did not do any trick. There is no difference on Action Bar :( Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: I tried this locally and it works.  I will post the code on your other link.

Comment: Can you help me solve my other issue ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361149/adding-multiple-header-in-drawer-list