# Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

My Project shows no errors. Though when I run the application it says please fix the error before running your application. When I looked at Console tab it says

```
    [2015-07-10 19:50:26 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions;
[2015-07-10 19:50:26 - NavigationDrawer] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions;
```

I tried searching for the solution but haven't got any.

this is what I have for my support libraries.

[image: Order and Export]

[image: Libraries]

Please Help. I got stuck here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have added multiple times this same library try to delete it to get only one (android-support-v7-appcompat.jar)

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what do I need to remove and from which tab? Order Export or Libraries ? Sorry I am new to this so asking such silly question. :(

Comment: Select library and click remove button.

Comment: Okay but which jar file should I remove? because the are total of 3. One is in  Android Dependencies which is android-support-v7-appcompat.jar and other two are in Android Private Libraries which are 1) android-support-v7-appcompat.jar  AND 2) android-support-v4.jar  which one should I remove?

Comment: Remove android-support-v7-appcompat.jar except library from appcompat_v7.

Comment: sorry total 4. There is android-support-v7-appcompat.jar on the top as well.

Comment: I see three android-support-v4.jar is ok.

Comment: Ok, remove last and first (at the top).

Comment: android-support-v4.jar is required by android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

Comment: Thankx. Error is gone now and launching app perfectly. :)

Comment: The Eclipse ADT plugin is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have added several times this same library try to delete it to get only one (android-support-v7-appcompat.jar).

I propose to remove last (at bottom) and first (at top).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you android program does, but from my experience these types of errors is the beginning of many erroes own eclipse. I recommend migrate their projects to AndroidStudio an excellent IDE that works without any kind of bugs.

Comment: How can I migrate my current project from Eclipse to Android Studio?

Comment: @akkie4396 You must do this: File -> Export -> Generate Gradle Build Files and after this launch Android Studio and you can import this project now.