# Adding Multiple Header in drawer list

Tags: java, android, xml, arraylist, android-listview

I want to add multiple header in drawerlist. Right now I am able to add just one header. How to I add header (like categories) in my drawer list?

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.pixalstudio.javaclasses;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    String[] mDrawerListItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConnectivityManager cManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nInfo = cManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (nInfo != null && nInfo.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Newtwrok Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        mDrawerListItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_list);


        ViewGroup header_news = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header, mDrawerList, false);
        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header_news, null, false);


        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDrawerListItems));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int editPosition = position + 1;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Have Selected " + editPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home: {
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                return true;
            }
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int editPosition = position + 1;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Have Selected " + editPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar">

    </include>


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawerList"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#CE93D8">

        </ListView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

nav_header.xml

```
    android:id="@+id/head1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header 1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried searching for the solution but every time I mess up with the code. Can someone give me perfect solution for this with code? Thank you in advance. :)

This is how I want like Title 1 and Title 2

[image: I want to add Titles like this after every list.]

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Header of `ListView` is just a regular view. You can put there what ever you want: even several copies of header.

Comment: @Foxinsocks  what I am trying to get is something like this.

Comment: @Foxinsocks    I have attached a pic of what I want. please have a look.

Comment: You have to google `stiky headers`, `listview groups` and `listview sections`. There're tons of libraries and tutorials.

Comment: @Foxinsocks   I already have one header if you see the code. nav_header.xml .. I want to add more below drawerList. how do I do that?

Comment: Look here : http://sunil-android.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html